# PM2 error while restarting a process. What is the cause?

Tags: node.js, pm2

After a few changes in code, I restarted the PM2 process and now I get this error

```
2|ngs-serv | /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/@pm2/io/build/main/pmx.js:230
2|ngs-serv |             const t/node_modules
2|ngs-serv |                   ^
2|ngs-serv |
2|ngs-serv | SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
2|ngs-serv |     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:16)
2|ngs-serv |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:27)
2|ngs-serv |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
2|ngs-serv |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
2|ngs-serv |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
2|ngs-serv |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
2|ngs-serv |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)
2|ngs-serv |     at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/@pm2/io/build/main/index.js:2:15)
2|ngs-serv |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
2|ngs-serv |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
```

What's the cause?

I tried updating all the global packages, deleting process and starting it from scratch

Comment: try deleting your node modules and reinstalling the packages